# Chrome driver version 92 not running tests

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I am having issues to run the version 92 with the browser open, in headless mode is working fine.

I am currently running my tests on a docker container. The installation of the chrome-driver follows:

```
RUN curl -s https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    xvfb \
    google-chrome-stable=92.\* \
    unzip

RUN curl -s -o /tmp/chromedriver.zip "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$(curl -s https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_92)/chromedriver_linux64.zip" && \
    unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/bin/ && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

after executing my command to run the tests, the browser open but nothing happens.
I get stuck on data; on the address bar, and page keeps loading forever.

I'm currently using the chrome options:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
```

[image: chrome version 92 stuck at data;]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was related to an old Nvidia driver running on Linux:

> You may need to run with --disable-gpu on Linux with NVIDIA driver older than 295.20

Source: [chromium documentation](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:docs/asan.md?q=disable-gpu&ss=chromium)

So, adding `chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")` solved my problem.

Comment: This solved the problem for us. Could you share your insights how you got to this solution/workaround/fix.

Comment: @user871611, I've edited my solution with my findings.